# Multiple webservers behind firewall done correctly?

Tags: firewall, ip, router, port, nic

Basiclly I have a firewall and behind it i have a webserver which is a webportal for clients, a second webserver that hosts their webpages
and a DNS server

I want to route the traffic through that one firewall. Is the correct way of doing this to use separate public ips for the webservers and route it to private ips with Multi-NAT on the firewall?

I assume the provider must route these public ips to the firewall, what do you in case you dont have access to more public IPs or if you dont want to spend IPs on this solution, are there any good methods for that?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, if you had multiple public IP addresses, then you wouldn't use NAT at all.  Just use normal routing and firewall rules.

If you only had one public IP address to work with, then you would give that address to the firewall, which would NAT everything behind it.  If your DNS needs to be publicly accessible, then forward port 53 to the DNS server.  (Better yet, replicate your DNS entries to a DNS hosting service.)  As for the two web servers, one of them would have to serve on a non-standard port (i.e., not port 80).  If that is not acceptable, then you could consider consolidating them onto one machine (where you could run name-based virtual hosts).  An uglier workaround would be to have one of them proxy requests to the machine.